# Expression tree to create dynamic Where clause throwing error related to params

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, expression

I've got a list of lists of conditions being sent up from the client.  I need to take this list and create a dynamic where clause to be executed by EntityFramework.

Each condition has an operator, an attribute, and a right-hand-side value.

Each list of conditions need to be ANDed together.

Each list of lists of conditions needs to be ORed together.

So if we had

```
{  
   "ConditionLists":[  
      [  
         {  
            "LhsAttributeDefinition":{  
               "attribute":{  
                  "key":"isHighBandwidth",
                  "value":"IsHighBandwidth"
               }
            },
            "Operator":{  
               "name":"equals",
               "description":"=",
               "validation":"",
               "inputType":"dropdown"
            },
            "RhsValue":"true"
         },
         {  
            "LhsAttributeDefinition":{  
               "attribute":{  
                  "key":"isForMobile",
                  "value":"IsForMobile"
               }
            },
            "Operator":{  
               "name":"equals",
               "description":"=",
               "validation":"",
               "inputType":"dropdown"
            },
            "RhsValue":"true"
         }
      ],
      [  
         {  
            "LhsAttributeDefinition":{  
               "attribute":{  
                  "key":"isHighBandwidth",
                  "value":"IsHighBandwidth"
               }
            },
            "Operator":{  
               "name":"equals",
               "description":"=",
               "validation":"",
               "inputType":"dropdown"
            },
            "RhsValue":"true"
         },
         {  
            "LhsAttributeDefinition":{  
               "attribute":{  
                  "key":"isForTablet",
                  "value":"IsForTablet"
               }
            },
            "Operator":{  
               "name":"equals",
               "description":"=",
               "validation":"",
               "inputType":"dropdown"
            },
            "RhsValue":"true"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

That should generate `.Where(x => (x.isHighBandwidth == true && x.isForMobile == true) || (x.isHighBandwidth == true && x.isForTablet == true))`

Here's what I've got to accomplish this using the Expression library:

```
MethodInfo contains = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
Expression finalExpression = null;
List<ParameterExpression> paramsArray = new List<ParameterExpression>();
foreach (var conditionList in conditionLists)
{
    Expression andGroup = null;
    foreach (var condition in conditionList)
    {
        Expression expression = null;
        ParameterExpression param = null;
        ConstantExpression constant = null;
        switch (condition.LhsAttributeDefinition.Attribute.Key)
        {
            case "title":
                param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "LearningItem.Title");
                constant = Expression.Constant(condition.RhsValue, typeof(string));
                expression = Expression.Call(param, contains, constant);
                break;
            case "isHighBandwidth":
                param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "IsHighBandwidth");
                constant = Expression.Constant(condition.RhsValue, typeof(string));
                expression = Expression.Equal(param, constant);

                break;
            case "isForMobile":
                param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "IsForMobile");
                constant = Expression.Constant(condition.RhsValue, typeof(string));
                expression = Expression.Equal(param, constant);

                break;
            case "isForTablet":
                param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "IsForTablet");
                constant = Expression.Constant(condition.RhsValue, typeof(string));
                expression = Expression.Equal(param, constant);

                break;

        }
        paramsArray.Add(param);
        if (andGroup != null)
        {
            Expression.And(andGroup, expression);
        }
        else
        {
            andGroup = expression;
        }
    }
    //OR the expression tree created above

    if (finalExpression != null)
    {
        Expression.Or(finalExpression, andGroup);
    }
    else
    {
        finalExpression = andGroup;
    }
}
MethodCallExpression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { query.ElementType },
    query.Expression,
    Expression.Lambda<Func<Activity, bool>>(finalExpression, paramsArray.ToArray<ParameterExpression>()));
return query;
```

So my thought is that inside of a nested for loop, I build the AND queries and the OR queries as one big expression, and then I create the lambda query at the very end.  I collect parameters along the way into a paramsArray (list).

My issue is that when executing, it blows up saying that `'ParameterExpression of type 'System.String' cannot be used for delegate parameter of type 'INOLMS.Data.Activity''`.  I'm assuming this is because the parameter I've collected so far is just a string (my example request body is just a single condition with IsHighBandwidth true), and it doesn't like that I'm taking a string parameter and trying to get an `Activity` query.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with the code that you currently have. Let's start with case by case.

Suppose you want to transform

```
{  
    "LhsAttributeDefinition":{  
       "attribute":{  
          "key":"isHighBandwidth",
          "value":"IsHighBandwidth"
       }
    },
    "Operator":{  
       "name":"equals",
       "description":"=",
       "validation":"",
       "inputType":"dropdown"
    },
    "RhsValue":"true"
}
```

into `.Where(x => x.IsHighBandwidth == true)`.

So first of all you have to built left side of expression which is `x.IsHighBandwidth` and you cannot simply define parameter of type string with constant value `IsHighBandwidth` (which is what you have done in `Expression.Parameter(typeof(string), "IsHighBandwidth")`. To do this you need first parameter of type `Activity` and then you call `Expression.MakeMemberAccess` with appropriate `MemberInfo` object representing desired property. Something like this:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Activity));
var accessorExp = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(p, typeof(Activity).GetProperty("IsHighBandwidth"));
```

Now that we have left side taken care of, let's take a look at the right side. If your property is of type `bool` and you want to do equality check then right side must match too. You cannot simply create string constant and expect some kind of magic to parse this to `bool` type. In our case we know that we expect bool value so we must parse string to bool first and then create constant expression of type `bool`:

```
bool value = Boolean.Parse(condition.RhsValue); // add error checks
var valueExpr = Expression.Constant(value);
```

Now that we have left and right side taken care of and of correct type, you can construct equality expression as you did in you code:

```
var expression = Expression.Equal(accessorExpr, valueExpr);
```

Now that we have body built (with `bool` expression type), we must construct lambda which will be passed as argument to lambda. As you see by C# code this lambda accepts exactly one parameter of type `Activity` and returns `bool`. You cannot send in multiple parameters as you did in your code. Example:

```
// Parameter p must be the same as was defined above
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expression, new [] { p });
```

And now that we have body you can construct new method call expression for `Where` as you did in your code, with one important difference: you must quote lambda expression if you want external parameters to work (this is what LINQ `Where` method does [behind the scene](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq.Queryable/src/System/Linq/Queryable.cs#L33)):

```
var whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { query.ElementType },
    query.Expression,
    Expression.Quote(lambda));
```

This should be sufficiently detailed to get you started. You must keep in mind that LINQ expressions are really low level and you must take care that you produce valid expression tree yourself. There is no compiler magic which you might be used to when programming in C# (for example implicit conversions).

Comment: Wow, that was super helpful.  Thanks so much!